# TinyMCE not working since Worpress 4.9.6

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

The wordpress TinyMCE editor doesn't display since Wordpress new version (4.9.6).

Here is the console error :

```
wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'name' on string 'f'
    at String.<anonymous> (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5)
    at Object.At [as each] (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:3)
    at s (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5)
    at er (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5)
    at Object.setup (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5)
    at new <anonymous> (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:5)
    at EC (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:3)
    at YC.<anonymous> (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:3)
    at Array.<anonymous> (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:3)
    at At (wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4711-20180425-tadv-4.7.11:3)
```

Tried to delete my browser cache and wordpress cache but the editor still doesn't display.

Is anyone having this issue? I thought wordpress was going to release a new version to fix this but unfortunately there is nothing yet.

**Did anyone solve this TinyMCE / Wordpress conflict yet?**

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controlManager' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I just found a temporary solution to make TinyMCE work: I desactivated the "**TinyMCE and TinyMCE Advanced Professsional Formats and Styles**" plugin and it fixed it.

This plugin lets you custom the style of your content editor to make it displayed as the users will see it, with the good fonts etc..

He is desactivated now but at least the wysiwyg is available and works again.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to a previous version of www/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/

This fixed it for me. Unfortunately, Wordpress 4.9.6 destroys some Plugins (such as the TinyMCE Editor) by its new privacy settings. This was also the reason why (for some time) Wordpress 4.9.6 had not been delivered via auto-update.

Comment: which is that version?